# jQuery toggleClass for z-index reordering only works once

Tags: jquery, css, video, z-index

I'm working on a jQuery function that will swap clicked on videos with a div of text specific to the video that you clicked on. To get the swap effect I want to apply a css class with a -10 z-index to the clicked on video div. ToggleClass works once and won't toggle back (i.e, put the video div back in front of the text).

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class = "container">
        <div id="box1" class = "box"> 
                <div id="text1" class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ut suscipit magna, ac imperdiet diam. Pellentesque quis tellus et nisi luctus efficitur vitae in quam. In maximus aliquam dui sed vulputate. Duis sed urna in ipsum efficitur ultricies at sit amet ligula. Curabitur feugiat placerat velit a mollis. Phasellus ac mollis metus. Pellentesque condimentum urna eu ex vulputate semper. Fusce pulvinar, dui id convallis aliquam, elit lectus convallis tellus, sit amet semper lectus nisl vehicula enim. Curabitur est augue, pharetra non orci vitae, rutrum fermentum nunc. Curabitur a tempor elit, et fermentum erat. Etiam iaculis nulla vitae nisl pretium venenatis. Maecenas convallis placerat vestibulum. Duis vel interdum quam. Nunc ultricies elit ut dolor bibendum commodo. Nam mollis diam tellus, non imperdiet purus facilisis in.Aliquam vitae malesuada lacus, a eleifend justo. Mauris in condimentum nisi, vel pulvinar magna. Suspendisse nibh augue, scelerisque in suscipit id, interdum sed arcu. Cras semper varius ante. Integer mollis, tellus quis interdum porttitor, ipsum dui venenatis elit, ut luctus magna est eu ex. Praesent pretium purus nisi. Duis pharetra aliquet diam, sed tincidunt enim. Mauris nunc sapien, mattis sed tincidunt sed, bibendum id eros. Pellentesque velit arcu, viverra id ipsum vel, venenatis hendrerit purus. Ut auctor quis ligula non laoreet. Proin id porta sapien. Nunc et felis id augue ultricies sollicitudin eget pellentesque justo. Etiam magna neque, tincidunt a quam in, varius suscipit quam. Cras tincidunt feugiat ex sit amet interdum. Aliquam sagittis turpis eu pulvinar convallis. Donec imperdiet euismod nisl et faucibus.</div>
                <div id="video1" class="video"> <video loop muted><source src=assets/IMG_1353.MOV></video></div>
        </div>
    <div id = "box2" class="box">
                <div id="text2" class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ut suscipit magna, ac imperdiet diam. Pellentesque quis tellus et nisi luctus efficitur vitae in quam. In maximus aliquam dui sed vulputate. Duis sed urna in ipsum efficitur ultricies at sit amet ligula. Curabitur feugiat placerat velit a mollis. Phasellus ac mollis metus. Pellentesque condimentum urna eu ex vulputate semper. Fusce pulvinar, dui id convallis aliquam, elit lectus convallis tellus, sit amet semper lectus nisl vehicula enim. Curabitur est augue, pharetra non orci vitae, rutrum fermentum nunc. Curabitur a tempor elit, et fermentum erat. Etiam iaculis nulla vitae nisl pretium venenatis. Maecenas convallis placerat vestibulum. Duis vel interdum quam. Nunc ultricies elit ut dolor bibendum commodo. Nam mollis diam tellus, non imperdiet purus facilisis in.Aliquam vitae malesuada lacus, a eleifend justo. Mauris in condimentum nisi, vel pulvinar magna. Suspendisse nibh augue, scelerisque in suscipit id, interdum sed arcu. Cras semper varius ante. Integer mollis, tellus quis interdum porttitor, ipsum dui venenatis elit, ut luctus magna est eu ex. Praesent pretium purus nisi. Duis pharetra aliquet diam, sed tincidunt enim. Mauris nunc sapien, mattis sed tincidunt sed, bibendum id eros. Pellentesque velit arcu, viverra id ipsum vel, venenatis hendrerit purus. Ut auctor quis ligula non laoreet. Proin id porta sapien. Nunc et felis id augue ultricies sollicitudin eget pellentesque justo. Etiam magna neque, tincidunt a quam in, varius suscipit quam. Cras tincidunt feugiat ex sit amet interdum. Aliquam sagittis turpis eu pulvinar convallis. Donec imperdiet euismod nisl et faucibus.</div>
                <div id="video2" class="video" > <video loop muted><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"/></video></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".box").find(".video").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("toggle");
        });
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".video").hover(function () {
            $(this).children("video")[0].play();
        }, function () {
            var el = $(this).children("video")[0];
            el.pause();
        });
    });
    </script>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    margin: 10%;
}

.box {
    background-color: blue;
}

#box1 {
    border: dotted;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
}

#box2 {
    border: dotted;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
}

.toggle {
    z-index: -10;
}

.text {
    font-size: large;
    width: 700px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

.video {
    position: absolute;
}

video {
    width: 700px;
}
```

Comment: Add a console.log(somethingsomething) to that click event on .video, I think you may be clicking on text1 when you think you are clicking video1 the 2nd time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").find(".video").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("toggle");
    });
    $(".box").find(".text").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings(".video").toggleClass("toggle");
    });
});
```

You are presumably clicking on the text div, so there is no click registered on the video div you sent to the back.